# Javascript trigger element when it first becomes visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting an element to animate at the correct time - ie, when it first comes into view on different sized viewports.

The code is:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.sright3').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+500) {
            $(this).addClass("slideRight");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This triggers the animation by adding class .slideright to the .sright3 element when it reaches 500 pixels below the top of the window. (topOfWindow+500) - the problem is that on different sized viewports, the element will either start animating too soon or only animate once it's half way up the screen.

Is there a way to define "bottom of window  - 100" or "top of window + 95% of window height"?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 95%: `$('body').height()*95/100`

Comment: bottom of window: $(window).height() -100;

Comment: i think what you want is that as soon as element become slightly visible class slideRight should get added right??